# Applescript: Using one list to weed out another list

Tags: applescript

So I have this list of words:

```
{{"YOU"}, {"KNOW"}, {"BETTER"}, {"THAN"}, {"TO"}, {"PARK"}, {"YOUR"}, {"CAR"}, {"IN"}, {"UNASSIGNED"}, {"SPOTS"}}
```

and I also have this list:

```
{{"0", "<SIL>"}, {"269", "YOU"}, {"389", "<SIL>"}, {"439", "KNOW"}, {"509", "BETTER"}, {"829", "THAN"}, {"969", "TO"}, {"1059", "PARK"}, {"1350", "YOUR"}, {"1449", "CAR"}, {"1839", "IN"}, {"2059", "<SIL>"}, {"2089", "UNASSIGNED"}, {"2659", "SPOTS"}}
```

I would like to weed out all the extraneous sublists (the ones that do not contain the words in the first list) leaving something like this:

```
{{"269", "YOU"}, {"439", "KNOW"}, {"509", "BETTER"}, {"829", "THAN"}, {"969", "TO"}, {"1059", "PARK"}, {"1350", "YOUR"}, {"1449", "CAR"}, {"1839", "IN"}, {"2089", "UNASSIGNED"}, {"2659", "SPOTS"}}
```

I'm new to applescript so this is really difficult for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is a site where users get help with writing code when they hit a stumbling block and need help working through the problem. So it is expected that you show that you are working on code not looking for someone to write it for you. Please show us where you are stuck in your code and we will be more than happy to assist

Comment: Sorry if I shouldn't have helped him, mcgrailm. I saw that he had properly formed applescript lists, so thought he had made a start. plz forgive.

Comment: no need to apologize :) Happy you could help him out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script cycles one at a time through the list pairs, and for each of them, checks each word from the original list to see if it's in that pair, and if so, add that pair to the resulting list.

```
set L1 to {{"YOU"}, {"KNOW"}, {"BETTER"}, {"THAN"}, {"TO"}, {"PARK"}, {"YOUR"}, {"CAR"}, {"IN"}, {"UNASSIGNED"}, {"SPOTS"}}

set L2 to {{"0", "<SIL>"}, {"269", "YOU"}, {"389", "<SIL>"}, {"439", "KNOW"}, {"509", "BETTER"}, {"829", "THAN"}, {"969", "TO"}, {"1059", "PARK"}, {"1350", "YOUR"}, {"1449", "CAR"}, {"1839", "IN"}, {"2059", "<SIL>"}, {"2089", "UNASSIGNED"}, {"2659", "SPOTS"}}

set L3 to {} -- initiate the resulting list
repeat with wordPair in L2 -- cycle through each list pair in L2
    repeat with wordSingle in L1 -- check each source word to see if found in the list pair
        if wordSingle is in wordPair then
            copy (wordPair as list) to end of L3
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end repeat
return L3
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something like that, but just couldn't get the syntax.